# What is the height dimension to mount a stove outlet in drywall above the kitchen floor?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, building

The stove outlet is a 50 amp,220 volt receptacle that is flush mounted.

Comment: Do you have a stove in mind?  The installation guide will typically show a zone where the receptacle should be installed so that the plug fits into a recessed area.

Comment: Some stoves have a recessed area in the back that goes from the floor to about 8 inches high, and the entire width, or almost, of the stove.  Check your stove to see where that area is.  It the stove to be flush with the wall with room for the plug and cable in the recess, whether or not the socket is flush mount.

Answer (score 0):

Architectural Graphic Standards indicate a minimum of 12” from finish floor to center of outlet, but I’d use the stove’s manufactures installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no minimum height in the national electric code.
When a new 4 wire is brought in in front of the wall the fixture a surface mount is touching the floor so the wires do not require a wireway or conduit.

I like to put the receptacle at the counter level so it can be removed by pulling the stove out a little it can be tough with it at a lower height but it’s all what you want.

Yes I understand you said flush mount but gave an extreme as an example.